# OpenCV not working with JavaFx

Tags: java, swing, opencv, javafx

I set up OpenCV 3.0.0 with intellij IDEA properly but i'm still getting errors when compiling my code.I'm trying to use it with swing embedded inside Javafx.

The program runs but it seems OpenCv is not working since the webcam is not turning on and the log errors seem to be opencv related

Here is my code.

```
private void createFrameContent(SwingNode swingNode){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JPanel frame=new JPanel();
                swingNode.setContent(frame);
                JLabel label=new JLabel();

                frame.add(label);


                ImageProcessor imageProcessor=new ImageProcessor();
                Mat webCamImageMat=new Mat();
                Image tempImage;

                VideoCapture capture=new VideoCapture(0);
                capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);
                capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240);

                if(capture.isOpened()){
                    while (true){
                        capture.read(webCamImageMat);
                        if(!webCamImageMat.empty()){
                            tempImage=imageProcessor.toBufferedImage(webCamImageMat);
                            ImageIcon imageIcon=new ImageIcon(tempImage,"");
                            label.setIcon(imageIcon);

                        }else{
                            System.out.println("not Captured...");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                    System.out.println("Capture failed !");
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

And these are the log errors

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:   105)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
   at org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture.VideoCapture_2(Native Method)
   at org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture.<init>(VideoCapture.java:54)
   at sample.Main$WindowPane$1.run(Main.java:68)
   at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
  ... 9 more
```

I also added the

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```

Comment: This is not enough information. How do you think anyone can make something out of the line numbers in the stacktrace? Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Did you try with plain JavaFX and does it work then?

Comment: @Roland I just  changed and used javafx only instead of using a mix of javafx and swing, I will post what i did soon

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Swing embedded in java fx, I just used only java fx and this is what i did

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    StackPane root=new StackPane(new MainWindow());
    Scene scene =new Scene(root,800,575);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Cam capture");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    launch(args);
}

class MainWindow extends BorderPane{

    private ImageView currentFrame;
    private boolean isCameraActive=false;
    private Button button;
    private ScheduledExecutorService timer;
    private VideoCapture videoCapture=new VideoCapture();

    public MainWindow(){
        currentFrame=new ImageView();
        button=new Button("Start");
        this.setCenter(currentFrame);
        this.setBottom(button);

        button.setOnAction(event->{
            if(!this.isCameraActive){
                this.videoCapture.open(0);

                if(this.videoCapture.isOpened()){
                    this.isCameraActive=true;

                    Runnable frameGrabber=new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Image imageToShow=grabFrame();
                            currentFrame.setImage(imageToShow);
                        }
                    };

                    this.timer= Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                    this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(frameGrabber, 0, 33, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }else{
                    System.err.println("Impossible to open the camera connection...");
                }
            } else{
                System.out.println("Cam is already active");
            }
        });

    }

    private Image grabFrame()
    {
        // init everything
        Image imageToShow = null;
        Mat frame = new Mat();

        // check if the capture is open
        if (this.videoCapture.isOpened())
        {
            try
            {
                // read the current frame
                this.videoCapture.read(frame);

                // if the frame is not empty, process it
                if (!frame.empty())
                {
                    // convert the image to gray scale
                    //Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                    // convert the Mat object (OpenCV) to Image (JavaFX)
                    imageToShow = mat2Image(frame);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // log the error
                System.err.println("Exception during the image elaboration: " + e);
            }
        }

        return imageToShow;
    }

    /**
     * Convert a Mat object (OpenCV) in the corresponding Image for JavaFX
     *
     * @param frame
     *            the {@link Mat} representing the current frame
     * @return the {@link Image} to show
     */
    private Image mat2Image(Mat frame)
    {
        // create a temporary buffer
        MatOfByte buffer = new MatOfByte();
        // encode the frame in the buffer
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", frame, buffer);
        // build and return an Image created from the image encoded in the
        // buffer
        return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));
    }
 }
}
```

Although i don't know why i I was getting the errors in the first place